# Any Ubuntu/Linux support for Gigabyte-990FXA-UD3?

Tags: 12.04, drivers

I recently got one Gigabyte gaming PC. It has high end AMD 8 core processor on Gigabyte-990XA-UD3 Ver 3.0 Motherboard. Unfortunately installation of Linux failed to start the ethernet(wired and wireless). I would like to know if someone has experienced anything similar (may be  on some other Gigabyte AMD board) and can provide me directions on how to fix it? Currently board boots with Ubuntu 12.04LTS, but it does not have ethernet (Both wired, and add-on card for Wifi do not gets enabled).

PS : Please redirect if this is not the correct forum for it!

Thanks.

Comment: post result of `lspci` and `sudo lshw -c network`

Comment: possible fix for nic: http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?60433-Gigabyte-GA-990FXA-UD3-for-Ubuntu&p=249557#post249557 Old but might be worth a try.

Comment: @web-E, I am unable to transfer anything from the board. now only is Ethernet not working, so is usb. lspci showed AMD family 15th processor, lshw showed RTL8111/8168B PCI Express gigabit eth controller and AR9300 wireless LAN adaptor(Atheros)

Answer (score 0):

Go into the BIOS and turn 'IOMMU' to "enabled" F10 to save/exit/reboot. I had the same problem, this is what fixed it- credit to the webs (search "IOMMU Ubuntu LAN" or something similar to view others' experiences).

Cheers!